# What is more efficient? Pre-rendering or mirroring directly?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, rendering

In my game I have characters that have sprites that are drawn onto a off-screen canvas upon creation of the character. Now sometimes the characters have to face a different direction that usual, so I mirror them. My question is now:
what is more efficient:

- Also pre-render the mirrored sprites so I can simply draw them onto
  the canvas
- Draw the sprites on a buffer and mirror them on it, then draw them
  onto my game's canvas
- Render them mirrored directly onto the canvas(for some reason always off by some pixels, prolly cause of rounding)

Comment: Too many factors to give a specific answer. I suggest benchmarking one method, then the other, and see what comes out better *in your specific situation*. (As this is tagged `html5`, there may also be significant differences across browsers etc.)

Comment: Well, I am optimizing for firefox, and what I see is that with few players it seems to be better with everything pre-rendered, however I experienced problems in another project when I had alot of off-screen canvases.